# getting parameters info from URI in Javascript Metro App Win8

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I'm developing a JavaScript Metro app in Visual Studio 2012 and Win8.1

I call my app using a URI on any webBrowser like:

```
myapp:///
```

but I want to send several parameters like this

```
myapp://parameters/?p1="hello"&p2="Jesus"
```

and recover the values inside my app for several purposes, is it possible?? how to do that??

thanks in advance

---

**EDIT:**

this is the code I got so far but still not working:

```
app.onactivated = function (args) {


    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        ...
    }

        //Handles URI activation (by Protocol)
    else if (args.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.protocol) {
        // Displays on screen the URI parameters
        console.log("the parameters: " + args.detail.uri.queryParsed);

        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
};
```

[image]

it says (translated from spanish):

> The value of this expression may not be correct. Unable to evaluate
>   because 'An identifier was expected' Click this button to attempt evaluation
>   now

this is the full error

> "TypeError: GetAt: invalid argument \n   at onactivated
>   (ms-appx://7f50cf46-2f92-4088-b44e-2da6ccd24a08/js/default.js:68:13)\n
>   at wrapper (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:549:61)\n   at
>   dispatchOne (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6987:25)\n   at
>   dispatchEvent (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6986:21)\n
>   at drainQueue (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:7038:9)\n   at
>   queueEvent (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:7057:13)\n   at
>   Anonymous function
>   (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:7110:13)\n   at
>   CompletePromise_then
>   (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1790:21)\n   at
>   activatedHandler (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:7109:9)"

---

**EDIT2:** This is what I did to get the closest thing to my answer so far URI

```
app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
         ...

        // Handles URI activation
        WinJS.Application.addEventListener("activated", onActivatedHandler, false);
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
};

function onActivatedHandler(eventArgs) {
    if (eventArgs.detail.kind == Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.protocol) {

        var uri = String(eventArgs.detail.uri.rawUri);

        var par1    = uri.substring(uri.indexOf("?p1=") + 7, uri.indexOf("&p2=") -3);
        var par2    = uri.substring(uri.indexOf("&p2=") + 7, uri.length - 3);

        Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("parameter1: " + par1 + ", and the parameter2: " + par2).showAsync();
    }
}
```

this shows a popup which says:

```
title
parameter1: hello, and the parameter2: Jesus
```

I Expected to get an array or dictionary of parameters...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. First check if your app has been activated by protocol 
(`eventArgs.detail.kind == Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.protocolol`  assuming eventArgs are activation event args) then you can access parsed query string object  via :

```
eventArgs.detail.uri.queryParsed
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I added the code on main post trying to apply your suggestion, but when I call the function I get this error (translated from spanish):           SCRIPT5: The JavaScript code library is about to catch the exception. in line 72, column 13 in ms-appx :/ / 7f50cf46-2f92-4088-b44e-2da6ccd24a08/js/default.js
0x800a0005 - Runtime Error in JavaScript? GetAt: Invalid argument
File: default.js, line: 72, column: 13     maybe I'm not setting the parameters on the right way this is my call   myapp://parameters/?p1="parameter1"&p2="parameter2"

Comment: strange, just checked on Win 8.1 and works perfectly. I test it by pasting myapp://parameters/?p1="parameter1"&p2="parameter2" to IE, did you add protocol declaration in package manifest ? Just checking :)

Comment: Yes I did, I called on that way before (IE and Firefox tested), I tried with and without arguments, on both ways it worked but now it interrupts normal flow on line: console.log("the parameters: " + args.detail.uri.queryParsed);

Comment: Not sure how I can help you, as the same code works in my app (WinJS 2.0 Win 8.1). Have you tried to set breakpoint there and inspect values of eventArgs.detail.uri ?

Comment: I added them, I'm going to update main question with screen captures, if pictures are not big enough just right click on them and "see picture" for showing them fullscreen on new tab

Comment: you have args.detail.uri.queryStr instead of Args.detail.uri.queryParsed

Comment: aww that's right, I was testing other properties but the result is the same, look updating the captures with your sentence

Comment: your code looks good, have you tried creating new sample project with the same code?

Comment: ok I'm going to rebuild code and test I'll get back with a new answer :)

Comment: I got the same error, the only way I found to get the URI is: Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("the parameters " + eventArgs.detail.uri.rawUri , "title").showAsync(); going to upload the code just to see if is this correct

Comment: I confirmed this problem. The app built by VS2012, the queryParsed brings error for Win 8.1 device, but it works for Win 10 device. The app build by VS2013 as Win8.1 app, the queryParsed works well for both Win 8.1 and Win 10 devices.